# Missing "Create new text file" context menu (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-8.1, context-menu

This is on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

When I right-click, the option to create a new text file is gone. How do I get it back? I know it's a registry setting but I don't know what to create.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. More information is available in **[ask]**.

Answer (score 1):

First Google result: http://www.anvisoft.com/plus/create-new-text-file-missing-from-conext-menu/

Basically:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]
@="txtfile"
"PerceivedType"="text"
"Content Type"="text/plain"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
```

paste it to notepad, save as *`something`*`.reg` and double-click on it.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly after associating Notepad++ with .txt files, I noticed that the Text Document option had disappeared from the Windows Explorer menu. Using regedit, I took a look in the Windows registry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt
```

The first thing I noticed was that the registry key was actually `.TXT` instead of `.txt`. Not only that, but the contents of the registry were not at all what they were supposed to be:

- The default was set to Notepad++_file
- Notepad++_backup was set to the text file
- ShellNew was set to Nullfile

This key obviously belongs to Notepad++ or one of its plugins. However, it is completely unnecessary to associate Notepad++ with the creation of text files in Windows Explorer's New context menu. Fortunately, there is a very easy and quick fix.

**IMPORTANT:** Always have recent a backup before making any changes to the Windows registry. A mistake can result in Windows failing to work correctly or even starting up again.

In my case, right-clicking on the .TXT key, renaming it to .TXT2 and pressing F5 immediately revealed the original .txt key.

If it doesn't for you, you can re-create it by copying and pasting the following as text file into Notepad or Notepad++ and saving it as ***fix-new-text-document.reg***. Last, double-click on the file to import it into the registry. Windows will likely ask you to confirm that you really want to do it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]

"PerceivedType"="text"
@="txtfile"
"Content Type"="text/plain"
```